# How to test mp3 upload in Django DRF, via PUT?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I try to test mp3 modification (hence PUT). I have the following so far:

```
client = Client()
with open('my_modified_audio.mp3', 'rb') as fp:
    response = client.put(
            f"/resource/{resource_id}/",
            data={'audio': fp})
```

However, I get `response.status_code == 415` because the serializer line in DRF's ModelViewSet
`serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)`.
fails with
`rest_framework.exceptions.UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.`

I have tried setting `format="multipart"`, setting the content type to json or form-encoded, nothing helped so far. The Resource model uses FileField:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

How can I make this put request work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @athansp's answer, I compared the source code of `client.post` and `client.put` and it turns out, put's implementation slightly differs from post, so a workable way of submitting files with put is:

```
from django.test.client import MULTIPART_CONTENT, encode_multipart, BOUNDARY

client = Client()
with open('my_modified_audio.mp3', 'rb') as fp:
    response = client.put(
        f"/resource/{resource_id}/",
        data=encode_multipart(BOUNDARY, {
            'other_field': 'some other data',
            'audio': fp,
        }),
        content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT
    )
```

Lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following will work:

The client:

```py
import requests
...

client = Client()
files = [('audio': open('my_modified_audio.mp3', 'rb'))]
url = f"/resource/{resource_id}/"

# response = client.put(url, data=None, files=files)
# You can test it using the `requests` instead of Client()
response = requests.put(url, data=None, files=files)
```

The serializer:

```py
class AudioSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """ AudioSerializer """
    audio = serializers.FileField(...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

The view:

```py
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView

class AudioView(UpdateAPIView):
   ...
   parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
   serializer_class = AudioSerializer
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @athanasp, I tried and it gave me error 415. Howerver, you've inspired me to look into django's code and found a workable solution after all.